# How can I ask partners about the addendums?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

A partner sent me a scan of the contract, where all conditions are detailed in the annex, but this annex wasn't attached. 
And now I need to ask partner about this annex to a main contract. How it will be better?

> *Would you be so kind to send me Annex A (or is "Application" better?) that is mentioned in the Contract?*
>
> *There is a reference to Annex A in the Contract. Could you please send me it*?
>
> *I would be appreciate if you would send me the Annex A that you made reference to?*

Or maybe  all are bad? Please give me advice.
I tried check these sentenses in google with "", but there wasn't any result 
Or maybe  all are bad? Please give me advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Sara. i am not sure that your question fits with the scope of ELL, so it may get closed soon. As it's your first question, I will give you a bit of advice anyway.  1) This is overly formal 2) this is fine  3) add an **it** after  **appreciate** and remove the question mark- it's not a question (2 is a question, though, and so its question mark is correct). You don't really need to use capital letters for "Annex" and "Contract". Please review this page before submitting your next question: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: Note that **addendum** has an unusual plural - it is **addenda**.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a document in the contract named "Annex A" or "Addendum A" then you can refer to the document in the same way when you request it.

> Kindly send me a copy of Addendum A mentioned in the contract (on page __).

"please send *me it*" is colloquial; if you are trying to craft a formal request, it should be changed to  "please send it *to me*".

Comment: Agreed - 'please send me it' sounds off, for some reason I can't quite put my finger on.  "Please send it" is fine, "please send me the file" is fine, but "please send me it" clashes.